# Polymer: Passing properties to child element doesn't work

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm trying to output data from a custom Polymer component `<data-component>` in an `<iron-list>` but nothing is shown when I open the page. It works when I pass an array of objects directly to the iron-list like `<iron-list items='[{"name": "test1"}, {"name":"test2"}]' >`

**What am I doing wrong here and is the `<template is="dom-bind" id="t">` mandatory?**

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../data-component.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../../iron-list/iron-list.html">    
    </head>
    
  <body unresolved>
        <template is="dom-bind" id="t">
            <data-component>
                <!--<iron-list items='[{"name": "test1"}, {"name":"test2"}]' > WORKS -->
                <iron-list items="{{data}}" >
                    <template>
                        <div>
                            Name: <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </iron-list>
        </data-component>
        </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### data-component.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="data-component">

  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
window.coolData = [
  {"name": "Bob"},
  {"name": "Tim"},
  {"name": "Mike"}
];


  Polymer({
    is: 'data-component',
    properties: {
            data: {
                value: window.coolData
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to specify the type of your data `type: Array`

Comment: @PascalGula good point. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are inserting the `iron-list` via the content tag or could you also place in the local dom of the `data-component`? That second approach would allow you to get rid of the `dom-bind`.

Comment: I would like to get rid of it but how do I place it in the local dom of `data-component`

Comment: just copy it instead of the `content` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to suggest an alternative answer to what I have already posted. If you want your `data-component` to always contain the `iron-list` then you can use this version here. However, if the content of the `data-component` should be more flexible use my other answer.

If you move the `iron-list` inside the `data-component` you can remove the `dom-bind` in your index.html.

**data-component.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="data-component">

    <template>
        <iron-list items="{{data}}" >
            <template>
                <div>
                    Name: <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                </div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
window.coolData = [
  {"name": "Bob"},
  {"name": "Tim"},
  {"name": "Mike"}
];


Polymer({
    is: 'data-component',
    properties: {
            data: {
                type: Array,
                value: window.coolData
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<body unresolved>
    <data-component></data-component>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow @Maria. I'm always hoping for some insightful answers like you provide here when I'm not sure whether I approach problems from the correct side.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to add a data-binding to your `data-component`. Otherwise, the system does not know that `data` (in your `iron-list`) should refer to the `data` property in your custom element.

```
<data-component data="{{data}}">
    <iron-list items="{{data}}" >
         ...
    </iron-list>
</data-component>
```

The `dom-bind` is necessary if you want to have data-binding outside of a Polymer element, which seems to be the case here.

You should also make sure that the `data` property is configured to notify changes and that its type is set to `Array`.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'data-component',
    properties: {
        data: {
            type: Array,
            value: window.coolData,
            notify: true
        }
    }
});
```